# How to fix only 3 images in HorizontalListView in both portrait and landscape mode

Tags: android-layout, android, horizontallist

I got a requirement where I need to set only **3 images for every scroll in horizontal listview** in  android like [this](https://github.com/Seitk/InfiniteScrollPicker). please help me out.Thanks in advance